# Unique variance conjecture: The ratio of a number to the variance of its divisors is injective

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

The variance $v_n$ of a natural number $n$ is defined as the variance of its divisors. There are distinct integer pairs whose variances are equal; the smallest such pair is $(691, 817)$. However I observed that for $n \le 10^8$ the ratio $\dfrac{n}{v_n}$ is different for each $n$. Is this true in general?

> **Unique variance conjecture**: The ratio of a number to the variance of its divisors is injective. There does not exist two distinct positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$ \frac{m}{v_m} = \frac{n}{v_n} $$

[A variation of this question with with standard deviation was posted here  was posted here and verified for $n \le 10^8$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176228/does-the-average-primeness-of-natural-numbers-tend-to-zero).

Comment: I would imagine that this is a strictly harder problem than similar questions about [perfect numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), for which some basic results remain unsolved.  Also, the sequence of perfect numbers [explodes incredibly quickly](https://oeis.org/A000396), so I think that checking up to "only" $10^8$ provides not very good evidence.

Comment: Well Skewes number has taught us that checking even up to $10^{100}$ would not have been good enough. So lets conjecture anyways :)

Comment: $(1)$ It might be helpful to know which formula for the variance you use $(2)$ The limit $10^8$ is impressing ! How did you manage to show that all the values are distinct in this range ?

Comment: @Peter You can find the definition of variance here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176228/does-the-average-primeness-of-natural-numbers-tend-to-zero  . To check up to $10^8$ I calculated the ratio for $n \le 10^8$ and then did a check duplicate to verify that none of the values repeated for $n \le 10^8$. So if there is a non-unique value, it must be greater than $10^8$. This was we can verify in $O(n)$ time. But if we are to compare each ratio with all the previous values then the program will run inefficiently in $O(n^3)$ time.

Comment: By sorting the values , I guess. Because comparing every value with every other should take a very long time.

Comment: @Peter We can do without sorting. The outputs  were all stored in a dataframe file and I just did a count unique on the file.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the software used in this tool uses also sorting, how else could we efficiently check for duplicates ? The complexity without sorting would be $O(n^2)$

Comment: @Peter yes all software do highly optimized internal sorting for giving unique counts. So at a user level we don't have to do it manually because it is taken care of by the programming language internally in the fastest way possible. E.g the function $unique(x)$ in $R$ removes all duplicate rows in the file $x$.